# Excel Countif Function not evaluating

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am having an issue with using the countif function in excel. I enter the formula into the cells and click enter, but it doesn't evaluate at all; it just shows the text of the formula.[Excel Formula Not evaluating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1QFi.png)

Please let me know what the issue is. Thank You!

Comment: Please include the contents of the cell (the formula) you're having trouble with so we can help debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Under 'Formulas' in the toolbar un-select 'Show Formulas':

[image]

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with the answer you can mark it correct to ensure others see the question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Number format in cells with the formulas set to TEXT?
If yes, apply General number format and then re-enter the formula in the cells.